# Account Currency Defaulting to USD instead of Corporate currency (Euro)

Tags: multi-currency, currency, convertcurrency, currencyisocode

I have multi currency enabled in my org with USD, GBP and EURO. EURO is my corporate currency. My user has Local currency as EURO. However, when I create an Account Record without entering the CurrencyISOCode. It is defaulting as USD instead of EURO. Why is this happening.

Comment: any WFR, PB, Flow, or triggers that coerce the CurrencyIsoCode?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was an existing application, and I did not know that there was a piece of Code which was Constantly changing the Account record Currency value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Account record defaults to a currency other than the user's currency (EUR) and there's no other data entry by that user to change the currency, it is likely that upon Save, one or more the following are coercing the currency to USD:

- Trigger + any called classes
- Workflow rule
- Process Builder
- Lightning Flow

Using the debug log should narrow this down (for example, a workflow rule would have a Field Update)